# go decode image unsupported type error

Tags: go

I'm trying to open a png image using the built in "image" package as such:

```
infile, err := os.Open(filename)
image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)
src, _, err := image.Decode(infile)
```

The `image.Decode` function is producing an error of `unsupported type *image.RGBA`. Anyone have any insight into this error?

I also tried this with a JPEG with the corresponding registration:

```
image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)
src, _, err := image.Decode(infile)
```

Which results in `unsupported type *image.YCbCr`. Very confusing as the image itself is in RGB.

Edit: also tried just importing `image/jpeg` and `image/png`, without using `image.RegisterFormat`, but still getting the same errors.

Edit #2: Apologies, the error I was getting was not even coming from the Decode function. The images decode properly.

Comment: How did you generate these images?

Comment: What version of go are you using?

Comment: go version: 1.8.3 and the images come from various data sets, I also tried it with the google logo from google.com

Answer (score 4):

**First the mistakes:**

You make a mistake when registering the formats.

The PNG magic is not `"png"` but `"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"`. So registration is:

```
image.RegisterFormat("png", "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)
```

The JPEG magic is not `"jpeg"` but `"\xff\xd8"`. JPEG registration:

```
image.RegisterFormat("jpeg", "\xff\xd8", jpeg.Decode, jpeg.DecodeConfig)
```

**BUT don't do this!**

Simply import the [`image/png`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/) and [`image/jpeg`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/) packages, the package init functions do this automatically for you. You may use the [blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) identifier if you don't use the packages (and you only do this for the initialization "side-effect"):

```
import (
    _ "image/png"
    _ "image/jpeg"
)
```

After the above imports, you will be able to decode PNG and JPEG images.

Comment: This answer is strange because his code worked for me out of the box, but it is good to know that you can just import the packages.

Comment: @BenjaminKadish Because in order for `png.Decode` and `png.DecodeConfig` to be valid, you already imported `image/png`, and its `init()` function was already executed.

Comment: @BenjaminKadish Ask him, maybe `png.Decode` refers to another `png` package in his code, or `png` may not even be a package identifier.

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors even using the import method :(. Tried this on a couple of different images as well.

Comment: @ZhaoLang When you do those imports, you have to remove the `image.RegisterFormat` calls. Also make sure the images you try to decode are valid images. If you still can't get it to work, please provide the **full** code and example image files.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by @icza. **Make it simple** just import packages "image/jpeg" and "image/png" (If we have to work with both image format.Otherwise import only specific package you  gonna use either "image/jpeg" or "image/png"). It works for me.

```
import (
    ...
    .
    . 
    _ "image/jpeg"
    _ "image/png"
    .
    . 
    ....
)
```